# Explain this weird result. Why isn't it binding?

Tags: angular, typescript

[Link](https://embed.plnkr.co/wc9QR25LyzHBbltCOFa8/)
Why are the name or id not displayed?

Comment: very good prepared example for question, in `plnkr`.

Comment: to debug your json data you can use `<pre>{{ yourJsonObject | json}}</pre>` in your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Hero` class doesn't have constructor with two parameters. So all your `Hero` object have empty properties

This should fix it

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string){}
}
```

[Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9Ez57mRJqcQ4gE5uPqv?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't actually have a constructor in it:

```
constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a constructor. Here is fix.

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(id: number, name: string){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```